# Get seconds until end of month in C++

Tags: c++, time

I have a requirement to get time interval until end of month in C++. Are there any C++ APIs which can easily do that for me?

I need to start a timer which will expire at the first day of next month at 00:00:00 hours. For that, I need to compute the time interval i.e. number of seconds from now till end of this month.

Comment: Look in the [<ctime>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ctime) header.

Comment: Have a look at [`std::chrono::duration`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration)

Comment: Are you looking for a precise output, or a reasonable approximation?

Comment: I need to start a timer which will expire at the first day of next month at 00:00:00 hours. For that I need to compute the time interval i.e. number of seconds from now till end of this month.

Comment: [Boost.DateTime](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/date_time.html) can do a lot for you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Its rather straight foward. Get the difference in `number of days` between *now* and the last day of the month. Then get `the number of seconds in a day`.

Now you have `the number of seconds till the end of the month`, now subtract that with `the number of seconds right now so far today` and you will get `the number of seconds until the end of the month`.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int day1,month1,year1;
    int day2,month2,year2;
    int i,temp,DaysDiff=0;
    int month[]={31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    int totalDiffDaysSecs=0;
    int nowSeconds=0;
    int expire=1000;

    time_t t = time(0);   // get time now
    struct tm * now = localtime( & t );

    cout<<"\n";
    day1=now->tm_mday;
    month1=(now->tm_mon + 1);
    year1=(now->tm_year + 1900);

    day2=31;
    month2=7;
    year2=2015;
    temp=day1;

    for(i=month1;i<month2+(year2-year1)*12;i++){
        if(i>12){
            i=1;
            year1++;
        }

        if(i==2){
            if(year1%4==0 && (year1%100!=0 || year1%400==0))
            month[i-1]=29;
          else
            month[i-1]=28;
        }

        DaysDiff=DaysDiff+(month[i-1]-temp);
        temp=0;

    }
    cout <<"Current Time = "<< now->tm_hour << ":" << now->tm_min << "."<<now->tm_sec<<"\n";
    cout <<"Today's date   "<< (now->tm_year + 1900) << '-' << (now->tm_mon + 1) << '-'   <<  now->tm_mday << " \n";
    cout <<"Target  date   "<< year2 << '-' << month2 << '-'   <<  day2 << " \n";

    DaysDiff=DaysDiff+day2-temp;

    cout<<"Target Month = "<<i<<"\n";
    cout<<"Days in Target month = "<<month[i-1]<<"\n";
    cout<<"Days diff Today - Target Month = "<<DaysDiff<<" \n";

    totalDiffDaysSecs=DaysDiff*24*60*60; 

    nowSeconds= (now->tm_hour  * 3600) + (now->tm_min * 60)+ now->tm_sec;

    cout<<"Total seconds in a day = "<<24*60*60<<" \n";
    cout<<"current total seconds so far today = "<< nowSeconds <<"\n";

    cout<<"Total number of seconds in "<< DaysDiff <<" days = "<< totalDiffDaysSecs <<"\n";
    cout<<"\n\n";

    while(expire>0){

       t = time(0);   // get time now
       now = localtime( & t ); 

       nowSeconds= (now->tm_hour  * 3600) + (now->tm_min * 60)+ now->tm_sec;

       expire=totalDiffDaysSecs - nowSeconds;

       cout <<"Seconds until end of month = "<< expire <<"   \r";   
    }


    cout<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"Countdown expired.\n\n";
return 0;
}
```